# PyCharm doesn't highlight kivy language (even after importing settings)

Tags: pycharm, kivy, syntax-highlighting, kivy-language

After following the instructions [found here](https://github.com/Zen-CODE/kivybits/tree/master/IDE) to import kv language syntax highlighting into PyCharm, I tried making a new kv file (which does appear to have a different icon than non-kv files) but it doesn't seem to highlight anything at all, or even just respect indentation.

In short, it appears like a regular text file, so I suspect something went wrong somewhere, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: If you are referring to "KV Lang Auto-completion and Highlighting", please refer to "Setting Up Kivy with various popular IDE's" (https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Setting-Up-Kivy-with-various-popular-IDE%27s)

Comment: I already followed those instructions and I didn't have to touch anything (as I only have one interpreter in the list), but somehow now it does seem to work (I also had already restarted PyCharm). Thanks.